# NodeJS ExpressJS Multer File Extension to lowercase

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to upload image by ExpressJS as Multer

I already know upload to path on my directory. but, i have some problems in here.

I Setup to upload only image/jpg, image/jpeg files. after upload, exactly renaming only ".jpg" with lowercase, Front-end users can upload (.JPG, .JPEG, .jpg, .jpeg)

but i can't find control file extension on Multer.

How to do this?

please help me. Have a good day.

```
app.post('/api/song/cover',
    multer({ //NOTE: Upload Parse From Multipart/data
        dest: './public/res/cover/',
        onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
            if (file.mimetype !== 'image/jpg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg') {
                return false;
            }
        },
        rename: function(fieldname, filename, req, res) {
            var payload = JSON.parse(req.body.data);

            return payload.key;
        }
    }),
    function (req, res, next) {
        //something do my scripts.
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because multer don't save the extension.
Acccording http://ewiggin.gitbooks.io/expressjs-middleware/content/multer.html

Comment: Thanks,
this posts multer version was 0.2.
I solved last day.